# Wait for Key Press from DOS driver under NTVDM During Initialization

Tags: assembly, driver, dos, x86-16, ntvdm

Is it possible to get keyboard input from a driver being loaded by **c:\windows\system32\config.nt** during the driver's initialization, when being run on 32-bit Windows 10 21H2 (OS Build 19044.1466) under NTVDM.exe? At this point I am just trying to simulate "press any key to continue..."

I've tried DOS APIs AH=08h INT 21h and BIOS API AH=00h INT 16h but both seem to freeze and not detect the input.

Code:

```
; *******************************************************************
; * Press Any Key To Continue DRIVER                                *
; *******************************************************************

cseg        segment para    public  'code'
presskey    proc    far
            assume  cs:cseg,es:cseg,ds:cseg

; *******************************************************************
; * MAIN PROCEDURE CODE                                             *
; *******************************************************************

begin:

; *******************************************************************
; * DEVICE HEADER - REQUIRED BY DOS                                 *
; *******************************************************************

next_dev    dd  -1              ; no other device drivers
attribute   dw  8000h           ; character device
strategy    dw  dev_strategy    ; address of 1st dos call
interrupt   dw  dev_interrupt   ; address of 2nd dos call
dev_name    db  'PRESSKEY$ '      ; name of the driver

; *******************************************************************
; * WORK SPACE FOR THE DEVICE DRIVER                                *
; *******************************************************************

rh_ofs      dw  ?               ; request header offset
rh_seg      dw  ?               ; request header segment
msg1        db  07h 
            db  'Press any key to continue...'
            db  0dh,0ah,07h,'$'
        

; *******************************************************************
; * THE STRATEGY PROCEDURE                                          *
; *******************************************************************

dev_strategy:                   ; first call from DOS
    mov     cs:rh_seg,es        ; save request header ptr segment
    mov     cs:rh_ofs,bx        ; save request header ptr offset
    ret

; *******************************************************************
; * THE INTERRUPT PROCEDURE                                         *
; *******************************************************************

dev_interrupt:                  ; second call from DOS
    cld                         ; save machine state on entry
    push    ds
    push    es
    push    ax
    push    bx
    push    cx  
    push    dx
    push    di
    push    si

; perform branch based on the command passed in the req header

    mov     al,es:[bx]+2        ; get command code
    cmp     al,0                ; check for 0
    jnz     exit3               ; no - exit go to error exit
    rol     al,1                ; get offset into table
    lea     di,cmdtab           ; get address of command table
    mov     ah,0                ; clear hi order
    add     di,ax               ; add offset
    jmp     word ptr[di]        ; jump indirect

; command table
;       the command code field of the static request
;       field contains the function to be performed

cmdtab  label   byte            ;
        dw      init            ; initialization

; *******************************************************************
; *     LOCAL PROCEDURES                                            *
; *******************************************************************

initial proc    near
    lea     dx,msg1             ; initialization
    mov     ah,9                ; message
    int     21h                 ; dos call
    mov     ah,0                ; wait for key press
    int     16h
    ret                         ; return
initial endp

; *******************************************************************
; *     DOS COMMAND PROCESSING                                      *
; *******************************************************************

;command    0   initialization

init:   call    initial         ; display a message
        lea     ax,exit         ; get end address (offset)
        mov     es:[bx]+0eh,ax  ; store offset address
        push    cs              ; get end
        pop     ax              ; address (segment)
        mov     es:[bx]+10h,ax  ; store in break address
        jmp     exit2

; *******************************************************************
; *     ERROR EXIT                                                  *
; *******************************************************************

; Set the done flag, error flag, and unknown command error code

exit3:  mov     es:word ptr 3[bx],8103h
        jmp     exit1                   ; restore environment

; *******************************************************************
; *     COMMON EXIT                                                 *
; *******************************************************************

; common exits fall thru code
;   2 sets status to done and no error
;   1 restore callers es:bx
;   0 restore machine state and exit

exit2:                                  ; set done flag and no error
        mov     es:word ptr 3[bx],0100h
exit1:  mov     bx,cs:rh_ofs            ; restore req hdr to bx and es
        mov     es,cs:rh_seg            ; as saved by dev_Strategy
exit0:  pop     si                      ; restore all registers
        pop     di
        pop     dx
        pop     cx
        pop     bx
        pop     ax
        pop     es
        pop     ds
        ret
exit:

; *******************************************************************
; *     END OF PROGRAM                                              *
; *******************************************************************


presskey    endp
cseg        ends
            end     begin

; that's all folks!
```

I'm building with masm:

```
masm presskey.asm
link presskey
exe2bin presskey.exe presskey.sys
```

Comment: In case it matters, what version of Windows are you testing with?  I don't know enough about the Windows and DOS details in this question to have any clue myself.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the call to `initial`?  If that works, you might try commenting out the call to print the prompt.  Calling back into DOS (int 21h) while a driver is being loaded might not be supported.  But that's just a vague guess.

Comment: Calling int 21h to print strings is fine just reading from keyboard seems to freeze

Comment: Hmm.  Reading input characters from the buffer (int 16/0) seems like a pretty simple task.  I can't think why that would hang.  But maybe the ISR that adds characters to the buffer can be blocked by a `cli`?  Since we're loading a device driver, I guess it might make sense for interrupts to be disabled until we're done.  Can you examine FLAGS?  For educational purposes: How about just calling STI a couple of statements before (ie not the line before) the INT 16?  Obviously another vague guess.

Answer (score 0):

It need not be true that the BIOS.WaitKey function 00h freezes the computer. It's probably your driver that freezes it because you forgot to setup a number of registers!

This `assume  cs:cseg,es:cseg,ds:cseg` is not enough on its own. You need to make sure that the `DS` and `ES` segment registers get the correct values.
For `DS` it is simply a copy from `CS`:

```
push    cs
pop     ds
```

And when your *dev_interrupt* routine is invoked, `ES:BX` needs to be set by your code. That's why we have a *dev_strategy* routine at all. You didn't do that and as a consequence you are overwriting the wrong memory and not returning 'DONE' to the RequestHeaderStatusWord or letting DOS know where the end of your driver is.

```
dev_interrupt:                  ; second call from DOS
    cld                         ; save machine state on entry
    push    ds
    push    es
    push    ax
    push    bx
    push    cx  
    push    dx
    push    di
    push    si

    push    cs               ADD THIS
    pop     ds               ADD THIS
    mov     es, rh_seg       ADD THIS    ; request header ptr segment
    mov     bx, rh_ofs       ADD THIS    ; request header ptr offset

; perform branch based on the command passed in the req header

    mov     al,es:[bx]+2        ; get command code
    cmp     al,0                ; check for 0
    jnz     exit3               ; no - exit go to error exit
    rol     al,1                ; get offset into table
    lea     di,cmdtab           ; get address of command table
    mov     ah,0                ; clear hi order
    add     di,ax               ; add offset
    jmp     word ptr[di]        ; jump indirect
```

Best also change that `rol al,1` into the less confusing `shl al,1` for clarity. But that's me of course...